# JMeter Office360 online : JavaScript required to sign in error while authorization

Tags: sharepoint, jmeter, performance-testing

When I try to login on sharepoint360 online site using JMeter, it gives JavaScript required to sign in error in response. I got below code in response.

```
<html>

<head>
<noscript>JavaScript required to sign in</noscript>
<title>Continue</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnBack() {}

function DoSubmit() {
  var subt = false;
  if (!subt) {
    subt = true;
    document.fmHF.submit();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:DoSubmit();">
<form name="fmHF" id="fmHF" action="https://ApplicationURL.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?apr=1&amp;wa=wsignin1.0" method="post" target="_self">
    <input type="hidden" name="t" id="t" value="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">
</form>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Sunil

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apache JMeter Homepage](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does

You need to extract the "value" attribute of that "t" hidden input and pass it along with other request parameters. I would recommend using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) for this.

Relevant configurations:

1. CSS/JQuery Extractor

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `t`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[id=t]`
   - Attribute: `value`
2. XPath Extractor

   - Use Tidy - check. If response is XHTML compliant it is not required however.
   - Reference Name: again, any JMeter Variable name, i.e. `t`
   - XPath Expression: `//input[@id='t']/@value`
3. Refer the extracted value as `${t}` where required
4. Handle any other dynamic parameters similarly and you should be good to go. JMeter doesn't execute JavaScript but it can capture and execute JavaScript-driven HTTP requests. Given you perform load testing you shouldn't worry about what is happened in browser as JavaScript is being executed on client side only. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how sharepoint authentication works, I believe you need to implement authentication using HTTP Request, instead of using login page, as explained [here](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/). Basically you will need 2 HTTP requests: first to extract the SAML token, and second to receive authentication cookies, which you can then use in the following HTTP requests, as you normally do.